# Add delay to the dissapearing of the text

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

i just created a custom loafding animatiuon using [GreenSock](https://gsap.com/), but i cannot figure out how to make it be delayed (i want the text to fill and then have a 1-2 sec delay so that people can see what is going on on the screen)

I have the code here:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/CustomEase.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Pre-loader
// Variables
// Custom ease
let customEase =
  "M0,0,C0,0,0.13,0.34,0.238,0.442,0.305,0.506,0.322,0.514,0.396,0.54,0.478,0.568,0.468,0.56,0.522,0.584,0.572,0.606,0.61,0.719,0.714,0.826,0.798,0.912,1,1,1,1";
// Counter start
let counter = {
  value: 1924
};
// Duration
let loaderDuration = 4;

// Duration, and counter start - if not a first time visit in this tab
if (sessionStorage.getItem("visited") !== null) {
  loaderDuration = 3;
  counter = {
    value: 1924
  };
}
sessionStorage.setItem("visited", "true");

function updateLoaderText() {
  let progress = Math.round(counter.value);
  $(".page-loader_text").text(progress);
}
function endLoaderAnimation() {
  $(".page-loader_trigger").click();
}

let tl = gsap.timeline({
  onComplete: endLoaderAnimation
});
tl.to(counter, {
  value: 2024,
  onUpdate: updateLoaderText,
  duration: loaderDuration,
  ease: CustomEase.create("custom", customEase)
});
tl.to(".page-loader_text-fill", {
    height: "150%",
    duration: loaderDuration,
    ease: CustomEase.create("custom", customEase)
}, 0);

</script>`your text`
```

Does anybody know where i should add the timeout function?

I have no clue what do do.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst looking at the documentation, `.delay(2)` seems to be what your looking for.

```
let tl = gsap.timeline({
  onComplete: endLoaderAnimation
});
tl.to(counter, {
  value: 2024,
  onUpdate: updateLoaderText,
  duration: loaderDuration,
  ease: CustomEase.create("custom", customEase)
});
tl.to(".page-loader_text-fill", {
    height: "150%",
    duration: loaderDuration,
    ease: CustomEase.create("custom", customEase)
}, 0);
to.delay(2);
```

Source: `https://gsap.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline/delay()`